# count Number of unique common substrings using kernel

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

We have two strings consist of characters. we define kernel of two strings as number of unique common substrings. how to proof number of unique common substrings is a valid function for kernel?
for example: s1 = "aa" and s2 = "aaa"
k(s1,s2) => {a, aa} = 2

Answer (score 1):

Imposing a maximum length over the strings and the size of the alphabet, we could form a feature matrix, $\phi(x)$ where each element is binary indicating the existence of the substring in $x$.

For example, if the alphabet is lowercase english letters, the first $26$ elements will be for checking the existence of one-letter words, i.e. $a,b,...,z$, and the next elements will check for the existence of two-letter words, $aa,ab,...,zz$ and so on. Here, if the string contains $aa$, the corresponding entry (i.e. 27-th here) will be $1$.

Then, the number of common substrings between $x$ and $y$ can be defined with the dot product $\phi(x)^T\phi(y)$, and this forms up our kernel. Since we defined the feature transformation explicitly, you don't need to prove if this is a kernel or not via symmetry and PSD check over the kernel matrix.